# jquery - .submit() function not working inside ajax() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax. The requirement is fairly simple. When the submit button is pressed, the javascript would do a asynchronous request, which the sever-side would validate the user input. If the input is alright, the form would do standard submit, otherwise have a error message.

So, here is my form:

```
<form id="form" action="dosomething.jsp" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="email">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var button =  $("#submit");
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ValidateServlet",
            type: "post",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg== ""){
                    form.unbind("submit");
                    form.submit();
                } else{
                alert(msg);
                button.removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code works fine, except one function `form.submit();` not working. I try this outside the ajax() function, it would submit, so I think there is problem about the scope, but I can't fix that.

Let me clarify the `form.unbind();`. Let say I delete the line with `form.submit();`, in other words, there is only `form.unbind();` for the success case `(if(msg = ""))`. When I press the submit button first time, the form would do a asynchronous request to validate as normal. If the input is correct, (namely `msg = ""`), when I press the submit button again, it would do the standard submit, since I have unbinded the submit event. Therefore, the problem is not on that `form.unbind();`, at least in my concern.

The servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String msg = "";
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    if("".equals(name)){
        msg += "<li>Please enter name</li>" ;
    }
    if("".equals(email)){
        msg += "<li>Please enter email</li>" ;
    }
    if(title.length() > 20 ){
        msg += "<li>Name should be lesser than 20 character.</li>" ;
    }
    if(email.length() > 30){
        msg += "<li>Title should be lesser than 30 character.</li>" ;
    }
    if(! "".equals(msg)){
        msg = "<p>Error :</p><ul>" + msg;
        msg += "</ul>";
        out.print(msg);
    } 
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: why you are submitting form again..?? just remove `form.unbind("submit");`

Comment: You could change the event to run on button click and remove the `form.unbind` and it would probably work out better.

Comment: `form.unbind ` is supposed to unbind the onsubmit event, and then perform standard submit. Not sure if it works like that.

Comment: which is the browser used

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using $.on() and $.off() to bind your events?

something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").on('submit',function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this);
        var btn =  $("#submit");
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ValidateServlet",
            type: "post",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg== ""){
                    frm.off("submit");
                    frm[0].submit();
                } else{
                alert(msg);
                btn.removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also try and avoid using 'form' as a variable name

Comment: what is your servelet returning? is it the empty string that we are testing for here `if(msg== "")` or should we try another test e.g. `if(!msg)`  ?

Comment: The msg is empty if the validation is correct. I could also include the servlet code. Actually, I have put a `alert()` inside `if(msg== "")` to test if the success case would run correctly, and it does. Therefore, it is not really matter. The only problem is the `form.submit()` could not run.